# I saw this on a post. Wouldn't f be an onto function, as its image is equal to its codomain?

Tags: functions

To be specific, here are two different ways of specifying the function that in a calculus class would just be called $x^2:$

$f=(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R},\{(x,x^2):x\in\mathbb{R}\})$

$g=(\mathbb{R},[0,\infty),\{(x,x^2):x∈\mathbb{R}\})$.

So in this formalism, $f$ is not an onto function, while $g$ is an onto function. Although $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$ in the domain of $f$ and $g$, $f\neq g$ since they have different ranges.

Comment: This is unreadable. Is $x2$ meant to be $x^2$?  And notions of "into" or "onto" make no sense unless you specify the intended domain and codomain of the function.

Comment: $f$ as described is not an onto function. Its image is $[0,\infty)$.

Notice how there is no $x$ such that $(x,-1)$ is graphed, for instance.

Comment: Use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset your mathematical formulas. Without that, this is unreadable.

Comment: Thank you to all. My bad about the copy and paste in readability. Thank you eevee trainer for the explanation...i see that the two Rs means that the codomain was defined as the set of real numbers, therefore the image, being the positive real numbers and 0, is not the same as the codomain.

Comment: I have also edited my post to make it more readable.

Comment: Note that, instead of mentioning domain and codomain as you did, it is more common if domain A and codomain B and function name $f$ to write that situation as $f:A \to B.$

Comment: yes, f and g are different because they have a different codomain. But they have the same domain and f(x)=g(x) for all x of the domain

Comment: f is not onto, but g is onto.